# Access 2003/VBA: Open Argument/WHERE in form sequence

Tags: ms-access

There are a sequence of forms A -> B -> C etc.

In A, parameters are asked from the users that will work as a where-condition for the table subset shown in B (with the DoCmd.OpenForm and "Detail"-method).

I also use the parameters in A to make a nice caption in B.

Problem 1: If there is no hit whatsoever in B (0 records shown), the parameter used for the caption (i.e. the search keyword for B's table contents) is lost, so I get an error. I tried to work around this by sending the parameter as an "open argument" as well - that will give the correct caption, only no search result (that is, correct result, if there is no hit). But, then, if you open the form from any other place, like the form menu in Access, you get the error.

Problem 2: I would like a "Back" button (A <- B, B <- C, etc.). I did it with just close first, but then I sometimes ended up in unexpected places. To use the above solution backward - well, first, it doesn't even work forward, second, even if it did, it seems so inefficient because that part of the search has already been done.

I described the problem from my view and experience, but don't feel "locked" by that. If you know an altogether different approach, please tell me.

Comment: I can see a few ideas, but perhaps you would like to say what you hope to achieve by the back button and whether forms remain open?

Comment: The back button is just to give the user a way to get back and correct the previous selection. It is a schedule for students, so if the manager would like to do something for group B, then realizes it should be group A, he or she would like to go back and redo it (but there are tons of parameters, otherwise I would use a singe form). As for open forms, they stay open but I could change this if it would help me. Because they stay open, most often the "Close" button will work as a "Back" button. But, I would like it 100% robust.

Comment: What does or does not happen with the close button that is a problem? If people are closing forms in the wrong order, that is easy enough to check.

Comment: Sometimes when you click it you do not see the form that I would like you to see but the Access overview page with the tables, forms, etc., menu to the left. I would like it to always lead to the form that preceded it, with the same data (typically a where condition) as it had, then.

Comment: How about in the open event of B and C you set the visibility of the previous form to false, then on the close button, check if the previous form is open and if it is, set the visibility to true. To ensure that you have the same data, you can programmatically set the record source rather than use a where statement. You can also check if any of the branch forms are open for any code that may re-open the forms. Setting visibility prevents open and load event code running and changing your data. It will also prevent people closing forms when the cannot see them!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can eliminate the error in the `OpenArgs` approach if you revise the code to only attempt to use `OpenArgs` when a value has been passed.

```
If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
    ' do something with OpenArgs
End If
```

Comment: Oh man, I tried this first thing, but made the mistake comparing null to null! But thanks.